# How do I pass a GET variable to my controller in my custom PHP framework?

Tags: php

This is the router for the controller. Now I want to be able to pass an ID or any data through the router to the controller, so that I can perform actions based on the data received like in Laravel.

**OLD** (what I have now)

```
$router->get('user-account', 'PagesController@account');
```

**NEW** (what I am looking for)

```
$router->get('user-account/{id}','PagesController@account');
```

This is the Request type router file which direct request to the router either it be POST / GET

```
<?php
Class Router {

    public $routes = [
        'GET' => [],
        'POST' => []
    ];

    public static function load($file)
    {
        $router = new static;
        require $file;
        return $router;
    }

    public function get($uri,  $controller)
    {
        $this->routes['GET'][$uri] = $controller;
    }

    public function post($uri,  $controller)
    {
        $this->routes['POST'][$uri] = $controller;
    }

    public function direct($uri, $requestType)
    {
        if(array_key_exists($uri, $this->routes[$requestType]))
        {
            return $this->callAction(
            ...explode('@', $this->routes[$requestType][$uri])
            );
        }

        throw new Exception('No routes defined for this URL.');
    }

    protected function callAction($controller, $action)
    {
        $controller = new $controller;

        if(! method_exists($controller, $action))
        {
            throw new Exception(
                "{$controller}  does not respond to the {$action} action."
            );
        }

        return $controller->$action();
    }

}
```

I want to be able to pass data to the functions in the pages controller through the router, like that of Laravel.

Comment: For some reason this code is super spaced out.

Comment: I don't get you Tadman

Comment: There's. Blank. Lines. Between. Every. Line. Of. Code. It's a minor thing, but it makes the code take up twice the space it should.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i will work on it ASP :)

Comment: So please does my problem got an answer?

Comment: Well I've reformatted the code... but as it stands there's nothing stopping you using `$router->get('user-account/{id}','PagesController@account');` (though you want `"` marks if you're attempting to interpolate an `$id` var) since all the `get()` method does is adds an index into an associative array...

Comment: Ok thanks, but previously when I try to interpolate an $id variable it  throws new Exception('No routes defined for this URL.');